# How to push to a shallow clone with Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

I have a repo in Azure DevOps which I require to clone and run some python code and then push the results back into the same repo.

Over time, the commit history/objects have grown larger and each run is taking longer. It looks like shallow cloning using `fetchDepth` may be the best option, but there is a lack of information implementing it in ADO as it cannot find the 'master' branch.

I get the following error: `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.` and `error: src refspec master does not match any.`.

It seems it cannot find master, how do I resolve this or what else can I try?

**azure-pipeline.yml**

```
jobs:
- job: Default
  timeoutInMinutes: 60
  pool:
    name: XXX
  workspace:
    clean: all 
  steps:
  - task: DeleteFiles@1
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: 
      Contents: '*'

  - checkout: self
    persistCredentials: false
    clean: true
    displayName: Checkout and clean
    fetchDepth: 3 #Shallow clone

  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        uname -a
        python3 --version
        pip3 install -r requirements.txt
        echo check system
        git clean -d -f
        pwd
        ls -l
        
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo "Running code"
        python3 some_script.py

        git config --global user.email "XXX.com"
        git config --global user.name "XXX"

        git add ../csv/
        git commit -m 'updated files'
        
        git push https://XXX:$(PAT)@XXX.visualstudio.com/XXX master
```

Answer (score 0):

`--depth` clone operation only pulls down one branch. If the remote repository contains other branches, they won’t be able to check them out locally without a pathspec error.

You need to clone explicitly the `master` branch:

```
git clone --depth 3 --branch master https://dev.azure.com/test/test/_git/test
```

Read [here](https://git%20clone%20--depth%203%20--branch%20renovate/configure%20https://tfs01.tipalti.com:8080/tfs/Tipalti/Tipalti/_git/apache-nifi%20testDepth) more info.